# Сокращения в библиографических списках

Tags: сокращения

Как правильно сократить слово "хантыйский"?

Answer (score 1):

При сокращении слов применяют разные способы, в нашем случае применяется **метод усечения**.

Прилагательные и причастия, оканчивающиеся на **-ийский**, сокращают отсечением этой части слова. Слов на **-ыйский** очень мало  — вполне возможно, что именно поэтому такого "окончания" и нет в таблице. Думаю, что сокращение должно быть аналогичным.

[Сокращение слов и словосочетаний по ГОСТ Р 7.0.12-2011](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/docs?layout=item&id=16_15)

Хантыйский — [**хант.**](http://slovari.ru/default.aspx?s=0&p=5474)
Марыйский — мар. (г. Мары́, Туркмения)
Янцзыйский — янцз.